# Right-hand side of instanceof is not callable

Tags: javascript

So, i'm trying to make a simple Discord Bot using javascript, and I want to detect if a player username is on the banned list.
I have an array

```
var banned = ['Andrew','David']
```

and an if

```
if (message.author.username instanceof banned) {.....
```

but when I run it, it outputs

```
if (message.author.username instanceof banned)
                            ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
```

What can I do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That is an improper use of `instanceof`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof has nothing to do with what you are doing - voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not what [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) is for.  `instanceof` is used to see if an object is an *instance* of a specific constructor (ex: `banned instanceof Array`).

If you just want to see if an element is in an array, you can use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
if(banned.indexOf(message.author.username) != -1)
```

Comment: I want to add that `Array.includes()` is the more idiomatic and readable variant. Pretty much supported everywhere by now!

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error on vue / nuxt js.

The problem was setting the prop type wrong:

```
blog: {
  type: {},
  required: false,
},
```

The right way doing it is setting the type Object instead {}

```
blog: {
  type: Object,
  required: false,
},
```

Comment: Thx, had the same issue. The correct declaration might be new Object() and not just Object.

Answer (score 5):

`instanceof` is used to check if an object is an instance of a class. What you want to do is to check if a string is in an array like this:

```
if (banned.indexOf(message.author.username) >= 0) {...
```

Answer (score 4):

`instanceof` is used to see if an object is of a particular type. You're trying to see if an object is a member of an array.

Try the `includes` or `indexOf` methods of the Array object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late here to answer, but I would definitely consider `includes()` when it comes to code maintainability and first impression of the code.

***ES2016 Specifications*** included the `includes()` for  Array data structure. The `includes()` check whether an array includes a certain element, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

But in ***ES5*** we are used to performing operations like this with indexOf() method.

**Why use `includes`?**

1. The `includes` method finds `NaN` and `undefined` whereas the `indexOf` method doesn't.
   **Example to find `NAN` in the array:**

   ```
   const  array = [NaN];
   if (array.indexOf(NaN) == -1){
       console.log("NaN not found in the array");//NaN not found in the array
   }

   const  array1 = [NaN];

   if (array1.includes(NaN)){
       console.log("true. NAN was found in the array");// true. NAN was found in the array
   }
   ```

   **Example to find `undefined` in the array:**

   ```
   const array = [, , , ,];

   if(array.includes(undefined)){
       console.log("true array elements are undefined");// true array elements are undefined
   } 

   const array1 = [, , , ,];

   if(!array1.indexOf(undefined) == -1 ){
       console.log("true. array elements are undefined");
   }else {
       console.log("Sorry can't find undefined");// Sorry can't find undefined
   }
   ```
2. The `includes` method does not distinguish between `-0` and `+0`(This is not a bug, but clearly how javascript works.

   ```
    const a = [-0].includes(+0);
    console.log(a);//true
   ```

In many cases, I have seen `indexOf` is little faster than `include`. It depends where you need to compromise. Also, ES6 `includes` performance is very fast as compared to lodash's `includes` method.

[Performance comparison source.](http://jsben.ch/5qRcU)